# Need help getting the frequency of each number in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a simple way of converting a pandas dataframe into another dataframe with frequency of each feature. I'll provide an example of what I'm trying to do below

Current dataframe example (feature labels are just index values here):

```
   0   1   2   3   4   ...   n
0  2   3   1   4   2         ~
1  4   3   4   3   2         ~
2  2   3   2   3   2         ~
3  1   3   0   3   2         ~
...
m  ~   ~   ~   ~   ~         ~
```

Dataframe I would like to convert this to:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   ...   n
0  0   1   2   1   1         ~
1  0   0   1   2   2         ~
2  0   0   3   2   0         ~
3  1   1   1   2   0         ~
...
m  ~   ~   ~   ~   ~         ~
```

As you can see, the column label corresponds to the possible numbers within the dataframe and each frequency of that number per row is put into that specific feature for the row in question. Is there a simple way to do this with python? I have a large dataframe that I am trying to transform into a dataframe of frequencies for feature selection.

If any more information is needed I will update my post.

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  There are many tutorials on the web, and many prior questions on Stack Overflow that deal with counting values in a data frame.  We expect you to do this research and post a valid coding attempt.  Stack Overflow is not a coding or design service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.value_counts` with `apply`:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0)

     0    1    2    3    4
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  2.0
2  0.0  0.0  3.0  2.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  0.0
```

**Alternative** [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
df2 = df.T.melt()
pd.crosstab(df2['variable'], df2['value'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't seem to find it on here even though apparently there is a similar question already. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Numpy

The value of this is speed.  But OBVIOUSLY more complicated.

```
n, k = df.shape
i = df.index.to_numpy().repeat(k)
j = np.ravel(df)
m = j.max() + 1

a = np.zeros((n, m), int)

np.add.at(a, (i, j), 1)

pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, range(m))

   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  1  1
1  0  0  1  2  2
2  0  0  3  2  0
3  1  1  1  2  0
```

This produces an index `i` that will correspond to the values in `df` that I assign to `j`.  I'll use these indices to add one at positions of an array `a` designated by the indices in `i` and `j`